# Where can I find detailed information on spacewalks?

Tags: iss, planning, eva

I am looking for detailed (as detailed as possible) information on the various space walks carried out on ISS. If I can get minute-by-minute steps taken, which bolts were turned, which wires were connected, etc, that would be awesome. Copies of that little checklist the astronauts have on their arms would be wonderful. I am also interested in large texts describing the general objectives of a spacewalk, the extra tasks if they complete things ahead of schedule, the contingency plans, timeline diagrams, stuff like this.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the publicly available procedural information you seek is on the Johnson Space Center Flight Data File [page](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/news/flightdatafiles/index.html).

It may help to briefly review the organization of the EVA checklist documentation.

The EVA Checklist document is just a list of all the documented procedures.
The Cuff Checklist is a sub-section of the EVA checklist and mostly deals with failure response.
The checklist for each specific EVA is built from the generic checklists with detailed additions as required.

- The cuff checklist (which is mostly responses to failures) is found inside the larger EVA Checklist. It's Section 15 of that [book](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/492872main_EVA_G_H_20.pdf).
  [image]
- The detailed procedures for three ISS EVAs are found on the same page.

[US EVA 10](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/209962main_useva10.pdf)

[US EVA 11](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/209963main_useva11.pdf)

[US EVA 12](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/209964main_useva12.pdf)

The detailed procedures have a lot of what you are looking for in them. They include

- A summary timeline - for EVA crewmembers (EV1, EV2) and
  the internal support crewmember (IV)
  [image]
- Pre EVA tool config
- Prebrief (a verbal summary of the tasks to be performed)
- Inhibit Pad (a list of devices to be turned off or reconfigured for
  safety such as antennas)
- Notes, Cautions and Warnings specific to this EVA
- The task section, broken down by crewmember. Often "task data" is supplied consisting of detailed drawings/photographs/specs for the task.

[image]
[image]
[image]

- Post EVA tool config